How to make nginx proxy to a specific directory
Let's imagine that we have some host on address www.host.address.com. And i have an account on this host on address login.host.address.com. I need to make a request on directory http://login.host.address.com/path/to/a/file.php from a website, that supports requests only to https addresses. So i make ngrok web interface that handle nginx localhost. And i need to proxy from nginx to that address of a file. How can i do it?
I tried to do
location / {
        proxy_pass 'http://login.host.address.com/path/to/a/file.php';
    }

But i don't know why when i'm making request to ngrok address it redirects me to http://www.host.address.com/path/to/a/file.php, so it changes my 'login' to 'www' of host. How can i solve it?
